# Use flask to get an image uploaded on a html form

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and i am using google colab to do some basic flask stuff.

I have a html-form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input accept attribute</h1>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <label for="img">Select image:</label>
  <input type="file" id="img" name="img" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then i have FLASK code as to get the uploaded image:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=['POST','GET'])
def test_page():
  if request.method == "POST":
    image = request.files.get('img', '')
    image = request.form["img"]

    print("img ",image)
    return "<h1> yo! </h1>"
  else:
    return render_template('index.html')
```

DEBUGGING RESULTS:

```
#debug
print('request.method', request.method)
print('request.args', request.args)
print('request.form', request.form)
print('request.files', request.files)

request.method POST
request.args ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.form ImmutableMultiDict([('img', 'cat.jpg')])
request.files ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

The problem is i want to doo some processing on the uploaded image but request.files return nothing and request.form just gives me the name. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `enctype` attribute should be defined within the form tag, not within the `input` element. This could fix the problem, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Yes correct. I want to make your ans correct one

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enctype attribute should be defined within the form tag, not within the input element. Here, the formatting of the data is defined when the form is transmitted.
This could fix the problem.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="img">Select image:</label>
  <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```